# Remove all Attribute from img except src and alt

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a html string that contains many images.each image has some attribute like class ,id , style , ....

I want remove all attribute from img except src and alt.

before :

```
<img title="How to" alt="How to" src="windows_en.jpg" loading="lazy" width="1280" height="720" class="img-first">
```

I want this output:

```
<img alt="How to" src="windows_en.jpg">
```

I want Remove all Attribute from img except src and alt.
I try this :

```
$desc = preg_replace("/(<img\\s)[^>]*((src|alt)=\\S+)[^>]*/i", "$1$2$3", $desc);
```

but not work fine. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of a regex, and then filter out the attributes that are not "src" or "alt" using [removeAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php):

```
$data = <<<DATA
<img title="How to" alt="How to" src="windows_en.jpg" loading="lazy" width="1280" height="720" class="img-first">
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("img") as $elm) {
  foreach(iterator_to_array($elm->attributes) as $att) {
      if ($att->name !== "src" && $att->name !== "alt") {
          $elm->removeAttribute($att->name);
      }
  }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<img alt="How to" src="windows_en.jpg">
```

Comment: Oh, this is a better approach. I was going the other way https://3v4l.org/e2Xa1

Comment: @user3783243 That is another way of doing it indeed. Maybe the OP is also interested in that approach, you can always post it.

Comment: You may omit `iterator_to_array` and iterate over `$elm->attributes` directly.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes you can, but if you omit that you will not get the desired output in this case https://3v4l.org/C9kFU

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the hint!